# Search any number, like phone number

Tags: excel, vba

How can I search for a number?

With this code, I can't search any number.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

If Len(TextBox1.Value) = 0 Then
    Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
Else
    If Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = True Then
        Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
    Sheet1.Range("b7:g" & Rows.Count).AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="*" & _
      TextBox1.Value & "*"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: A TextBox contains text and, therefore, a string. "*88*" will not find a number 88, only a string "88". There is no backdoor to this "deficiency" because any change would have to affect the data you search, not the search string your code creates.

Comment: ok thanks for your advise, any better code can search both, word and number, please guide me

Comment: Please reverse your approach. First you should know what kind of data you want to search. Where would you get data which have either text or numbers in one column? If such data exist treat the data, by column, before you search. Once you have modified your data, why would you want a single procedure to search either numbers or text? The two search operations are separate and different from each other. A strong case could be made for using different functions to conduct the searches.

Comment: Do you want the number to match anywhere in the string  or just the beginning ?

Answer (score 0):

You can build you own selection criteria using a regex which treats all entries as strings. It's probably OTT but it gives you a lot of flexibility should you need it in the future.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    Dim iLast As Long
    iLast = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' create regex pattern
    Dim sPattern As String
    sPattern = CStr(TextBox1.Value)

    'create regex engine
    Dim Regex As Object
    Set Regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With Regex
      .Global = True
      .MultiLine = False
      .IgnoreCase = True
      .Pattern = sPattern
    End With

    ' build selection array
    Dim r As Long, i As Long, s As String, ar() As String
    ReDim ar(iLast)
    i = 0
    For r = 7 To iLast
       s = CStr(ws.Range("B" & r).Value)
       If Len(s) > 0 And Regex.test(s) Then
         ar(i) = s
         i = i + 1
       End If
    Next
    ReDim Preserve ar(i)

    ' apply filter
    If Len(TextBox1.Value) = 0 Then
        ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    Else
        ws.Range("B7:G" & Rows.Count).AutoFilter Field:=1, _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues, _
        Criteria1:=ar
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks It's work , but i still have 1 small problem , i still have another one TextBox2, located at column c, i try to amend the code you provide but still cant search ....i just start to learn vba coding, so can you guide me some i already change all b to c and name it textbox 2 but still no work

Comment: Did you change the line sPattern = CStr(TextBox1.Value) ? If you want the filter to work on both textbox1 and textbox2 at the same time that gets complicated !

Comment: AutoFilter Field:=2 for column C if sort range is B:G